# Extending classes, will they inherit parameters if I follow this manner?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

If I create a a base object like so:

```
public abstract class RIBaseObject{
    static ObjectRegistry sSystemRegistry = new ObjectRegistry();

    public RIBaseObject() {
    }

    public abstract void reset();

}
```

And extend this base object in every(most) classes I make, considering ObjectRegistry contains parameters like these:

```
public class ObjectRegistry extends RIBaseObject {

    public BufferLibrary bufferLibrary;
    public CameraSystem cameraSystem;

    public ObjectRegistry() {
        super();
    }

}
```

Would declaring bufferLibrary this way in a bootstrap class:

```
RIBaseObject.sSystemRegistry.bufferLibrary = new BufferLibrary();
```

Make it that from any class extending BaseObject, I would access the same bufferLibrary object? Or would it differ?

Comment: This looks to be a terrible circular design. A parent class holding a static field of its child type? No, parents should have no dependence on their children. You need to re-think your design.

Comment: This is taken from Replica Island.. I'm just trying to understand how that guy got his stuff together. But, terrible design, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the subclasses will access the same static variable in base class.
static variables are loaded once per class, they don't depend on the instantiation.

so all your sub classes will share the same static variable ie your library defined as static in your base class.

static variables are not inherited but can be hidden by similarly defined variables in subclasses known as variable hiding.

so YES, you would access the same bufferLibrary from all sublclasses.

Comment: Ok, so since sSystemRegistry is static, there is only a new ObjectRegistry the first time RIBaseObject is constructed. Then "new" doesn't mean new anymore, it's merely making it point to the already created sSystemRegistry. That's what needed to click in my head, thanks.